# How to efficiently render mesh surface with the polygon edges outlined?

Tags: opengl, graphics

Given a VBO and an EBO for the vertices and elements of a triangle mesh, I want to render the surface in one color and render the edges in another color so that I can construct some image like this:

[image]

One way to do this is to call glDrawElements once for the wire-frame and once for the filled geometry. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way? Perhaps, with one single draw call?

Comment: So you're just changing `glPolygonMode` and drawing twice?

Comment: I also need to update the color by either switching between programs or passing the new color to FS. I am wondering if there is any better way to do it. Many software/toolkits like VTK, Blender, Rhino such options, so I am curious to see if OpenGL has a more convenient way to address this.

Comment: @mfaieghi: The fact that complex rendering engines can do this in no way obligates OpenGL to have a way to do it that is simple or "convenient". Indeed, the whole point of complex rendering engines is to take things that are complicated at the low-level and make them simple at the high level.

Comment: Well, this can be done in a single draw call by just drawing triangles and conditionally decide on drawing with edge color or ordinary shading on a per-fragment basis, based on the distance to the edges (you can also nicely mix between the two to get some line-smoothing).

Comment: @derhass Thanks for the great point. Do you have an example that I take a look at?

Comment: @mfaieghi: [Easy wireframe display with barycentric coordinates](http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/)

Answer (score 3):

You're drawing with two different kinds of [primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive), with two different sets of rendering parameters (ie: the color to write), and therefore almost certainly two different *shaders*.

Even if you used an ubershader approach, a single draw call can only rasterize a single kind of primitive. A draw call draws triangles or lines, not both. And while a GS can convert triangles into lines or vice-versa, that is a [*compile-time* determination](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Primitive_in.2Fout_specification).

The only way to do this is by rendering the object twice, with different rendering parameters/shaders/whatever else is needed. Even [indirect multidraw commands](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Indirect_Rendering) can't do this in one go.